# Check keydown value after the keydown event to prevent keydown

Tags: jquery, keydown

I am using the following code to test a editable td cell if the value inside is bigger than 99 (value after entering a new number).

```
$(document).on('keydown',"#checkvaluenumber", function (e) { 
   if( $(this).html() > 99) {    
     e.preventDefault();
}
    });
```

due to the keydown event the test value is the value before the keydown event.
I know I can skip to keyup so it would use the value after the new digit input but I would like to prevent any number that is higher than 99 and it does not prevent anything with "keyup" method.
Any solutions?

best greetings and thank you in advance!

Comment: Its better to write some JS for keyup to restrict user to enter number greater than 99 OR use input type number with max value as 99

Comment: do you have any JS examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EBs33/1/
and its working great!

But I added the code to my td field and its still reaction too late. so its testing the value that is already there and only skip the value to 100 if its already over 100.

```
 $(document).on('keyup keydown',"#checkvaluenumber", function (e) { 
   console.log($(this).html() > 100)

  if( $(this).html() > 100 && e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 8 ) { 
     e.preventDefault();     
     $(this).html(100);
}
    });
```

is this code only working for an input instead of my editable td cell?

Comment: hmm seems to work now ... should be the correct answer ... maybe was a cache issue ... just in case some is looking for the same solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this . Check this fiddle for working code. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBs33/1014/)

```
$('.td-with-class').on('keyup input paste', function () {
    if (isNaN($(this).val())) {
        $(this).val('');
    }

    if ($(this).val() > 99) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you but I would prefer a solution without any alert.

Comment: @hillcode I have removed the alert,Can you check now

Comment: seems a legit solution but I prefer setting it to the max value in my example. thanks